# Flip a landscape environment

Tags: pdftex, rotating, landscape

I have a page that needed to be in landscape mode, so I've used something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[1]
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

This does rotate my page. But unfortunately, I wanted it to be rotated the other way round (page number to the right) so that you would read the paper version from the edge of your book to the binding.

How should I do? Is there an argument of `landscape` allowing this?

EDIT: In my actual case, there won't be only text on the landscape page, but also a figure which I would like to point *down* to the binding.

Comment: Please elaborate further: Should the landscape-mode pages be turned 180 degrees depending on whether they occur on odd-numbered/right-hand-side/recto pages of on even-numbered/left-hand-side/verso pages?

Comment: @Mico Ideally yes. But if I could flip it manually, that would be fine :)

Comment: Flipping the orientation of the landscape mode pages like that is actually a downright awful thing to inflict on your readers, you know that, right?

Comment: @Mico I am not sure. I like better reading from the outside edge of the report to the middle than the other way round. And this is not the point anyway, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the [rotating package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating):

[image]

Using the `sideways`, `turn` and `rotating` environments you can put display the page prettty much anyway you want.

Here's the code for the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{report}
\usepackage{mwe}% only for images
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}\quad\newpage% only for creating the image

\begin{sideways}
  \includegraphics[width=16cm]{example-image-a}
\end{sideways}

\begin{turn}{-90}
  \includegraphics[width=16cm]{example-image-b}
\end{turn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work fine.. as long as I don't try to use `\captionof` inside. But it'll maybe work if I wrap it into a `minipage`.. lemme try õ.Ô

Comment: @lago-lito There's also a `sidewaystable` environment in the rotating package which may play better with caption...not sure, as I haven't used it.

Comment: Mmh, I don't have much time. But I've got what I wanted with `turn` + `minipage`. Thank you Andrew :)